# How do I round numbers in Java?

Tags: java

For this program I am writing I am taking a user's input of minutes and rounding up to the next hour. 
For example:

- 1 minute = 1 hour
- 59 minutes = 1 hour
- 60 minutes = 1 hour
- 61 minutes = 2 hours
- 119 minutes = 2 hours
- 120 minutes = 2 hours
- 121 minutes = 3 hours

What is a simple way of going about this? Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not a dupe given that it's specifically to do with the *presentation* of floating point numbers rather than the *assignment* of "ceilinged" integral values to another variable.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming it's an integer that will truncate when divided, it's a simple matter of:

```
int hours = (minutes + 59) / 60;
```

The following table shows the results:

```
minutes                   hours
-------   ----------------------------------------
    1     (  1 + 59) / 60   ->    60 / 60   ->   1
   59     ( 59 + 59) / 60   ->   118 / 60   ->   1
   60     ( 60 + 59) / 60   ->   119 / 60   ->   1
   61     ( 61 + 59) / 60   ->   120 / 60   ->   2
  119     (119 + 59) / 60   ->   178 / 60   ->   2
  120     (120 + 59) / 60   ->   179 / 60   ->   2
  121     (121 + 59) / 60   ->   180 / 60   ->   3
```